# Considerations when replacing a Mixin with abstract Model subclass?

Tags: django, django-models, abstract-class, mixins, subclassing

I have multiple Models that all need some shared functionality.

My existing code uses a Mixin class:

```
class MyMixing:
    some_class_variable = None

    @classmethod
    def get_headers(cls):
        return [field.name for field in cls._meta.fields]        
    # ...
```

and my models look like:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The above code shows an example, where my IDE shows error, because `MyMixin` doesn't have `_meta`.

And there are multiple such issues, especially as I'm trying to add some more common functionality

So I'm thinking it might be better to replace `MyMixin` with `MyModel`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    some_class_variable = None

    @classmethod
    def get_headers(cls):
        return [field.name for field in cls._meta.fields]
```

then my models will look like:

```
class Something(MyModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Could this mess up my existing data?

Other than database (and, of course, silly typos), is there anything else that might go wrong with that change?

Comment: If there is no field, there is not much reason to work with an abstract model. Then a mixin is just more flexible.

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike what's this about mod strike?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an